# Maven Build Failure, Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I've searched and searched to no luck resolving this issue. Can someone please advice me on what I can do to resolve this?

running the following command in my working project workspace

```
mvn compile
```

Produces the following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project acme: Could not resolve 

dependencies for 
project com.acmecorp.acme:acme:war:GUI 5.0: Failed to collect dependencies at 
org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE: Failed to read artifact descriptor
for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE: Could not transfer 
artifact org.springframework:spring-core:pom:4.0.2.RELEASE from/to central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX 
path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

Yes i've checked my proxy in the settings.xml file in the .m2 folder. Here is what it looks like.

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
       <active>true</active>
       <protocol>https</protocol>
       <username>USER</username>
       <password>PASS</password>
       <host>proxy.host.com</host>
       <port>80</port>
     </proxy>
     <proxy>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username>USER</username>
        <password>PASS</password>
        <host>proxy.host.com</host>
        <port>80</port>
      </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

OS Windows 7

Comment: download jar by maven update

Answer (score 1):

You need to get ssl certificate of maven repo server and copy that into your local jre/lib/security folder.

Steps: 
1. Download this Java program https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/180292346/InstallCert.java

2. Compile
3. Run with command line parameter maven repo server
4. Copy the generated ssl to your local JRE/lib/security

For detailed steps pl follow this post:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Comment: Can you provide some instructions on how to do that?